# Backbone.js - ncaught exception: SyntaxError: Function constructor: failed to compile function

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk

And I stuck at this part (video starts after the part I start getting the error):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=FZSjvWtUxYk#t=1678

As I see in the error it has something to do with underscore.js template.

```
Uncaught exception: SyntaxError: Function constructor: failed to compile function

Error thrown at line 637, column 3 in <anonymous function: T.template>(e, t, n) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js:
    throw u.source = s, u
called from line 57, column 12 in <anonymous function: success>() in file://localhost/home/andrius/dev/backbone/beginner/index.html:
    var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models}) ;
called from line 442, column 4 in <anonymous function: a.success>(d, e, f) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js:
    c && c(b, d)
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 870, column 5 in <anonymous function: p.Callbacks>(b) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    if (i[h].apply(b[0], b[1]) === !1 && a.stopOnFalse)
called from line 915, column 5 in <anonymous function: fireWith>(a, b) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    return b = b || [], b = [a, b.slice ? b.slice() : b], i && (!d || j) && (e ? j.push(b) : k(b)), this
called from line 3650, column 4 in y(a, c, f, i) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    x.status = a, x.statusText = (c || y) + "", k ? o.resolveWith(m, [s, y, x]) : o.rejectWith(m, [x, y, t]), x.statusCode(r), r = b, j && n.trigger("ajax" + (k ? "Success" : "Error"), [x, l, k ? s : t]), q.fireWith(m, [x, y]), j && (n.trigger("ajaxComplete", [x, l]), --p.active || p.event.trigger("ajaxStop"))
called from line 3879, column 6 in <anonymous function: d>(a, e) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    l && f(h, j, l, k)

Error initially occurred at line 634, column 3 in <anonymous function: T.template>(e, t, n) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js:
    var o = new Function(n.variable || "obj", "_", s)
called from line 57, column 12 in <anonymous function: success>() in file://localhost/home/andrius/dev/backbone/beginner/index.html:
    var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models}) ;
called from line 442, column 4 in <anonymous function: a.success>(d, e, f) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js:
    c && c(b, d)
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 870, column 5 in <anonymous function: p.Callbacks>(b) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    if (i[h].apply(b[0], b[1]) === !1 && a.stopOnFalse)
called from line 915, column 5 in <anonymous function: fireWith>(a, b) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    return b = b || [], b = [a, b.slice ? b.slice() : b], i && (!d || j) && (e ? j.push(b) : k(b)), this
called from line 3650, column 4 in y(a, c, f, i) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    x.status = a, x.statusText = (c || y) + "", k ? o.resolveWith(m, [s, y, x]) : o.rejectWith(m, [x, y, t]), x.statusCode(r), r = b, j && n.trigger("ajax" + (k ? "Success" : "Error"), [x, l, k ? s : t]), q.fireWith(m, [x, y]), j && (n.trigger("ajaxComplete", [x, l]), --p.active || p.event.trigger("ajaxStop"))
called from line 3879, column 6 in <anonymous function: d>(a, e) in http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:
    l && f(h, j, l, k)
```

**My code** (don't see any difference in my code and videos..)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BackboneTutorials.com Beginner Video</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>User Manager</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="page"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
    <table class="table striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user.get('firstname')  %></td>
            <td><%= user.get('lastname')  %></td>
            <td><%= user.get('age')  %></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        <% )}; %>
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </script>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script>

    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
      options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
    });

    var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: '/users'
    });

    var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',
      render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var users = new Users();
        users.fetch({
          success: function () {
            var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models}) ;
            that.$el.html(template);
          }
        })        
      }
    });

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        '': 'home'
      }
    });

    var userList = new UserList();

    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:home', function () {
      userList.render()
    });

    Backbone.history.start();

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be closing your _.each loop. You have  <% )}; %> which should be  <% }); %>

Comment: Thank you for noticing. That was the problem. Ah those brackets..:)

Comment: No problem! :) Your IDE should give you warnings about that type of stuff. Cut down on the headaches!

Comment: Yeah. I think I need better tool for this, to see such errors:)